# How to write a program that would keep taking inputs from the user until the sum of all the inputs reach 200

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The numbers permissible for the user input are: 10, 20 and 50. If any other number is entered, then the program should declare it as invalid.

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work out:

```
count = 0
total = 0
print("Enter the values of amounts collected")

while True:
    new_number = input('> ')
    count = count + 1
    total = total + int(new_number)
    if total==200 :
        print("You have successfully collected 200")
        break
    if total>200:
        print("Amount collected exceeds 200")
        break
```

Sample input:

```
> 10
> 50
> 50
> 50
> 10
> 20
> 10
```

Sample output:

```
You have successfully collected 200
```

Sample input:

```
> 190
...
```

Sample output:

```
Invalid input
```

Sample input:

```
> 50
> 50
> 50
> 20
> 50
```

Sample output:

```
Amount collected exceeds 200
```

Comment: So what part isn't working as expected? From your code example, you haven't put any constraints yet on the input, so that shouldn't work (as expected). is your question how to perform a check on multiple values?  If so check out the python [in](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_in.asp) keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You just need nested `if` condition

```
total = 0
print("Enter the values of amounts collected")
while total<200:               # Loop in until total < 200
new_number = int(input('> '))
if new_number in [10,20,50]:   # First check input number is in 10,20,50
    total = total + new_number # Then add sum to total

    if total == 200:           # If total = 200 break
        print("You have successfully collected 200")
        break

    elif total >200:           # If total > 200 break
        print("Amount collected exceeds 200")
        break
else:                         # If number not in 10,20,50 then print invalid input
    print("Invalid input")
```